# multilinearform over finite dimensional vector space is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

How do I prove that a multilinearform over a finite dimensional vector space is continuous? So, think of a multilinear map $A:V_1 \times ... \times V_n \rightarrow W$. Why is this always continuous?(I am looking for a proof that does NOT use that $A$ is bounded.)

Comment: Because it's a polynomial in the coordinates, basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $V_j = span\{e^i_j\}$ and write
$$
A(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n) = \sum \alpha^1_{j_1}\alpha^2_{j_2}\ldots \alpha^n_{j_n} A(e_{j_1}, e_{j_2}, \ldots, e_{j_n})
$$
Now let $M$ be the max of all the terms $\|A(e_{j_1}, e_{j_2}, \ldots, e_{j_n})\|$.

Does that help?

Alternatively, perhaps induction on $n$ might also work.

Comment: This is of course the standard technique (as far as I know), but I wonder, is there any other way to obtain this result?

Comment: why does this maximum exist?( I have troubles to see how your $e_{j_1},...,e_{j_n}$ are related to the span given by you)

Comment: @Lipschitz There are only finitely many combinations of basis vectors, so the maximum is taken of a finite set.

Comment: ah, thank you Daniel Fischer, I did not understand the meaning of this notation.