# Multilinear form is bounded-is this proof correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A: V_1 \times ... \times V_n \mapsto W$ a multilinear form on finite-dim vector spaces.

Then $$ ||A(v_1,...,v_n)||\le  ||v_1||\cdot...\cdot ||v_n|| C $$

Proof: $||A(v_1,...,v_n)|| = ||v_1||\cdot...\cdot ||v_n||||A(e_1,...,e_n)||$ and since A is continuous and the cartesian product of boundaries of the unit spheres, that are compact is compact(Tichonoff) over finite-dim vector spaces(conclusion from Riesz-Lemma). $||A(e_1,...,e_n)||$ is also bounded for arbitrary unit vectors $e_1,...,e_n$. Hence the theorem is proved.

Comment: Sure. But didn't you just ask this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494604/multilinearform-over-finite-dimensional-vector-space-is-continuous

Comment: It's not quite as easy. Generally, the $V_i$ are not one-dimensional, so you'd have to write $v_i = \sum c^i_j e^i_j$.

Comment: @DanielFischer No, I meant $ e_i = \frac{v_i}{||v_i||}$   and this should be possible for every combination of $v_1,...,v_n$. Prahlad, it is similar but not the same :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry stopped reading early. If you at some point mention that if one argument is $0$ the result is $0$ and hence the inequality trivially holds, it's okay.

Comment: Thank you very much(to both of you)

Answer (score 2):

The proof given is not correct.

The proof given by the OP uses the fact that $ A $ is continuous. There is a theorem stating that a multilinear form is continuous if and only if it is bounded. If it was known that $ A $ is continuous, then using this theorem, the proof would be done.

The OP might be happy to make this assertion using the following question asked by the OP:
[multilinearform over finite dimensional vector space is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494604/multilinearform-over-finite-dimensional-vector-space-is-continuous).
However the answer to that question shows that $ A $ is bounded, despite the OP asking for a different proof.

So, firstly (as noted by Daniel Fisher) is any of the $ v_1, \dots, v_n $ is zero the inequality holds trivially.

If none for $ v_1, \dots, v_n $ is zero, then the OP is correct that $ \| A(v_1, \dots, v_n) \| = \| v_1 \| \cdot \dots \cdot \| v_n \| \cdot \| A(e_1, \dots, e_n) \| $, where $ e_i = \dfrac{v_i}{\| v_i \|} $ using multilinearity.

As noted above, continuity can not be used to obtain a maximum for $ \| A(e_1, \dots, e_n) \| $. However since $ V_1, \dots, V_n $ are finite dimensional, a finite unit basis $ \{ b_{j_i} \} $ can be found for $ V_i $ for each $ i = 1, \dots, n $.

So for any $ e_1, \dots, e_n $ such that $ \| e_i \| = 1 $ for any $ i = 1, \dots, n $ we can write for some constants $ c_{j_i} $,
$$
\| A(e_1, \dots, e_n) \| = \sum_{j_1, \dots, j_n} |c_{j_1}| \cdot \dots \cdot | c_{j_n} | \| A(b_{j_1}, \dots, b_{j_n}) \|.
$$
Let $ M = \max_{j_1, \dots, j_n}(\| A(b_{j_1}, \dots, b_{j_n}) \|) $ and show that $ \sum_{j_1, \dots, j_n} |c_{j_1}| \cdot \dots \cdot | c_{j_n} | = 1 $, then the desired result is obtained
$$
\| A(v_1, \dots, v_n) \| \leq \| v_1 \| \cdot \dots \cdot \| v_n \| \cdot M.
$$